# Why does accessing 'window.variable' return 'undefined' when using 'let' but not with 'var'?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascript-scope

Consider the following code snippets:

```
// Using var
var val = 20;
console.log(window.val); // Outputs: 20
```

```
// Using let
let val = 20;
console.log(window.val); // Outputs: undefined
```

In both cases, `val` is declared in the global scope, yet accessing `window.val` returns `undefined` when using `let`, while it correctly returns 20 when using `var`.

How `var` and `let` differ in their interaction with the global object (`window` in a browser environment).

Comment: Why? Simply because that's how it was designed to work. Implicitly polluting the global object was bad to begin with, so it is no longer done.

Comment: Gopika, you can accept only one answer as 'the' answer. So, accept the one that you find the most helpful. You should stop changing them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two points in here:

1. variables declared with `var` in the global scope are added as a properties to the global object and making them accessible as properties of that object.
2. variables declared with `let` and `const` in the global scope are not added as a properties to the global object. They exist in the scope but do not create properties on the global object

Answer (score 1):

From- [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781491952016/)

> Globals declared with `var` are implemented as properties of the global
> object. The global object can be referenced as globalThis. So if you
> write `var x= 2` outside of a function, it is like you wrote
> `globalThis.x = 2`.

> Global variables and constants declared with `let` and `const` are not
> properties of the global object.

In web browsers, the `Window object` serves as the global object for all JavaScript code
contained in the browser window it represents. This global Window object has a self referential window property that can be used to refer to the global object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is `undefined` Here it is why?

- When you declare a variable with `var`, it is hoisted to the top of its scope (including the global scope) and becomes a property of the global object. Hence, when you access `window.val` after declaring `var val = 20`, you can retrieve its value, which is 20.
- On the other hand, variables declared with `let` have block scope, meaning they are only accessible within the block in which they are defined. In this case, the block is the global scope. However, unlike `var`, `let` variables are not added as properties to the global object. Therefore, when you try to access `window.val` after declaring `let val = 20`, it returns undefined because `val` is not a property of the global object.